# Does the sum of the smallest n primes give infinite primes?

Tags: number-theory

Consider the sequence $A_n$ given by the sum of the smallest n primes. Does this sequence contain infinitely many primes? Shown are such primes given by $n\leq 1000$. I cannot even find a nice direction to approach this problem; any relevant discussions are welcome.

2,
5,
17,
41,
197,
281,
7699,
8893,
22039,
24133,
25237,
28697,
32353,
37561,
38921,
43201,
44683,
55837,
61027,
66463,
70241,
86453,
102001,
109147,
116533,
119069,
121631,
129419,
132059,
263171,
287137,
325019,
329401,
333821,
338279,
342761,
360979,
379667,
393961,
398771,
581921,
642869,
681257,
687767,
700897,
754573,
768373,
782263,
868151,
935507,
958577,
1005551,
1086557,
1313041,
1359329,
1583293,
1603597,
1686239,
1749833,
1891889,
2051167,
2086159,
2133121,
2156813,
2180741,
2327399,
2364833,
2402537,
2504323,
2556187,
2582401,
2608699,
3120833,
3238237,
3557303,
3619807

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A013918 , https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04198

Comment: I think , this has been asked already. The problem is open , although we can strongly expect infinite many primes of this form.